# Bracha for "Zero Net Carb" Bread

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, bread

A company called "Thin Slim Foods" makes a product called "[Zero Net Carb Bread](https://www.thinslimfoods.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8&products_id=48)" under the Kosher Miami hechsher. It has the form and texture of bread and is made from ingredients *derived* from the 7 grains (such as "oat fiber" and "wheat protein isolate") but does not contain any grains per se.

Do I have on what to rely if I want to wash on bread like this? What would the appropriate bracha be for this "bread"?

Thank you

> Ingredients: wheat protein isolate, vital wheat gluten, oat fiber, modified wheat starch, flaxseed meal, olive oil, chicory root, yeast, chopped onions, poppy seeds, sesame seeds, minced garlic, salt, apple cider vinegar.

Comment: Probably best to ask the Kosher Miami hechsher not us. We couldn't possibly know how it is made

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) jonaz and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Sounds like *she'hakol*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked Kosher Miami (info@koshermiami.org) and they responded **the blessing was sheakol** (as pcoz suggested in comments as well). So there is no way to wash on bread like this and its final blessing is *borei nefashos*.

Comment: Did they explain the reason?

Comment: They wrote it as I did. Short and to the point

Comment: I ask b/c if the only difference from regular bread is that they remove some of the starch, why wouldn't it still be hamotzi - e.g. if they use a process like this one: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/wet-milling

Comment: (even if they render it inedible in the interim - which I doubt(?) - the question should perhaps hinge on how one treats gelatin halachically)

Comment: For some reason my link doesn't seem to work.  The article should start: "Wet milling of wheat is the process of separating flour into its components, primarily starch and gluten, using water in the process. This can easily be illustrated in a household kitchen. Take some flour and add enough water to form a dough ball and then knead the ball for a few minutes to allow the gluten to form. Slowly rinse this ball with water; the starch will wash out, leaving behind the gluten in a dough form."

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that Kosher Miami said that. I have asked this question before from CRC and gotten a different answer. I asked about bread with wheat gluten and almond flour. This was the response (quoted exactly):
If wheat gluten is added for its nutritional value as well as its taste, then the bracha rishona would be hamotzoy when made into bread and mezonos when made into crackers. However the bracha acharona would be more complicated.
If there is a כזית בכדי פרס of the wheat gluten in the almond flour, and you are eating an amount of the bread or crackers that contain a כזית of the wheat gluten then you would recite an על המחיה/ברכת המזון . If not, the bracha achrona would be בורא נפשות.